# Polymer; Local webserver works, dropbox doesn't. suspect: https

Tags: javascript, polymer, web-component

Using Polymer I am able to host my files on a local http server, however when uploading the files to the public directory of Dropbox the page no longer renders.

The only major difference I can see between my local server and dropbox, is that dropbox is serving the pages over https.

No errors that I can see appear in the console.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents.js"></script>
<script src="keys.js">
</script>
<script src="script.js">
</script>
<link rel="import" href="bower_components/core-elements/core-elements.html">
<link rel="import" href="bower_components/google-map/google-map.html">
<link rel="import" href="key-list.html">
```

--snip--

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see errors in the console. Definitely an issue with https.

```
 Mixed Content: The page at 'https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/11144544/keys/v2/index.html' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure stylesheet 
'http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,300,500,700|Source+Code+Pro'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
```

Try using https for that google font, or hosting the font files in the same domain.

Comment: How did you get the console error to appear? In chrome I don't see a thing.

Comment: I dunno. I didn't do anything special. Try restarting chrome, maybe? Or check to see if it needs an update by going to chrome://chrome